# php insert query enum as a string from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, sql, enums

im sorry im a newbie, i have a case when i want to insert my data from php, insert query enum to mysql,
this is my code,

```
<tr>
            <td><label for="passwd">Password</label> </td>
            <td>: <input type="password" autofocus required name="passwd" id="passwd" value="<?php echo @$data['password'] ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="jabatan">Jabatan</label> </td>
            <td>: <select>
                    <option value="1"<?php if ?>Keuangan</option>
                    <option value="2">Sales</option>
                    <option value="3">Admin</option>
             </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

when the $data is

```
$data = Karyawan::getDetail($_GET['id']);
        if ($data) {
            $var = array(
                'title' => 'Karyawan |',
                'rows' => Karyawan::get(),
                'data' => $data
            );
```

when the getDetail is

```
static function getDetail($id) {
    $query = sprintf("select * from karyawan WHERE id='%d'",$id);
    $exe = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe);
    return $row;
```

what am i suppose to do? please help me

Answer (score 0):

why you write if instead of value

`<option value="1"<?php if ?>Keuangan</option>`

please change to

```
<option value="1">Keuangan</option>
```

and change HTML.(**please add name field to pass data from FORM**)

```
              <select name="jabatan" >
                    <option value="1">Keuangan</option>
                    <option value="2">Sales</option>
                    <option value="3">Admin</option>
             </select>
```

and get value using

```
 $jabatan = $_REQUEST['jabatan'];
```

Insert Query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO karyawan (`field_1`,`field_2`) VALUES ("$password","$jabatan") ");
```

Comment: whoops sorry my bad, but i mean, how to type the query to insert to my database enum, when my enum like this "enum('keuangan', 'sales', 'admin')", please help

Comment: enum is manage from your database. it doesn't matter in your insert query. simply get value and store in any variable like  $jabatan and $password and write insert query as i mention

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the enums as values on the select:

```
<select name="jabatan" >
    <option value="keuangan">Keuangan</option>
    <option value="sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```